# sendMultipartTextMessage doesn't send arabic messages

Tags: android, unicode, smsmanager

the next function takes the message from resources By calling getString(R.string.invitation_format). invitation_format is my message, When it is in English, all work fine, but when invitation_format in Arabic the message will not be send..
note: the values in the variable "parts" is correct even if it in Arabic

```
private void SendSms(String to) {

String SMStext=getString(R.string.invitation_format);

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

ArrayList<String> parts=smsManager.divideMessage(SMStext);

smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(to,null,parts , null, null);
Toast.makeText(context,SMStext+"   \nSent to : "+to ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Is `divideMessage()` dividing up Arabic text correctly? Is there any error being reported by `sendMultipartTextMessage()` when the text is Arabic? Do you have the same problem with `sendTextMessage()`?

Comment: divideMessage() does the work fine, I print the parts and see that divideMessage() divided the message into 2 parts. No Exepions with sendTextMessage()

Comment: sendTextMessage not sending on me. any solutions?